# how to esacpe single quotes for codeigniter form_validation

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am trying to show validation error if single quotes are passed with the below function, but its not working out

```
  function alpha_dash_space($str) {
        return (!preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
```

-

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<li  class="errorlist">', '</li>')->set_rules('book_title', 'Book Title', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[150]|xss_clean|callback_alpha_dash_space');
```

**Example:**

If input provided for book_title = `The Roa'r of King's`

Expected validation error message should
show "`Book Title has invalid character`"

if "`The Roar of Kings`" of passed then there will be no validation error.

Comment: pls give examples of input and expected matches.

Comment: @nozzleman Thank you! i have updated my question. Please find the update above

Answer (score 2):

If you're validating form input rather use CodeIgniters own implementation. Your form validation rules should look like the below.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'alpha_dash');
```

Comment: I tried but this didn't worked out as i expected! I provided title `The Roar of Kings`  but it shows validation exception i.e `The Book Title field may only contain alpha-numeric characters, underscores, and dashes.` which it should not suppose to show!    , I am expecting it should show validation exception if this two keyword present i.e `'

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
function custom_alpha_dash_spaces($str) {        
    if (!preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_ -])+$/i", $str)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('custom_alpha_dash_spaces', 'The %s can not contain quotes.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    return true;
}
```